# Hard time counting records using CDbCriteria

Tags: yii, count, criteria

When I try to use CDbCriteria to count records I get **Active record "Hotels" is trying to select an invalid column "count(t.`id`) as `count`".**

Here is my code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select = 'count(t.id) as `count`, t.`keywords`, min(offers.first_bookin) as first_bookin';
        $criteria->with = array('offers');
        $criteria->group = 'offers.hotels_id';
        $criteria->compare('first_bookin','>' . date('Y-m-d'));
        $criteria->together = true;

        $hotelItems = Hotels::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

And here are my relations defined in Hotels model:

```
return array(
            'headers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Headers', 'hotels_id'),
            'offers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Offers', 'hotels_id'),
        );
```

I red a lot of posts here and on some other sites, but nothing seems to work. I tried with count(*), count(id), I tried splitting the select property into an array. Every time I get the same error.

Comment: Thanks guys. It worked without the backticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the **backticks** from the alias and the count should work. Of course if you want to access the count easily you will have to declare it as a class variable, as mentioned by onkarjanwa.

If you check the source of the error, it's this function: [`getColumnSelect`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php#L921) of `CActiveFinder`, the select for count should satisfy this line, in `getColumnSelect`:

```
elseif(preg_match('/^(.*?)\s+AS\s+(\w+)$/im',$name,$matches)) // if the column is already aliased
```

but because of the backticks in the alias name, it doesn't match, and it throws an error. So your `select` should be without the backticks for aliases:

```
$criteria->select = 'count(t.id) as count, t.`keywords`, min(offers.first_bookin) as first_bookin';
```

When i was testing this, i got another error in your `compare`, so you should change it to:

```
$criteria->compare('offers.first_bookin','>' . date('Y-m-d')); // can't use the alias in where clause
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable `$count` because Yii does not automatically initiate variables that are not table columns, so you can't use any new variable without declaring that.

You can solve your problem by doing this.

Declare a model variable:

```
class Hotels extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $count;
    ....

}
```